# Create case with automatic macro in social studio

Tags: case, facebook, social-studio

I am working with social studio and so far I have had good results and I am even creating cases from social studio to salesforce. But when they comment on the facebook wall in social studio, I must assign the macro to which it is linked to create a case.

Can I create cases without the need to assign the macro to the post?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. If you find yourself in this situation, some automations for social studio can be found in ["Social Studio Automate"](https://rules.radian6.com/login)

https://rules.radian6.com/login

here I managed to generate a case every time people comment on the facebook wall.

I hope to help you.